# _start.cshtml view is not executing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using `Asp.Net MVC-4` in my application. I have created a controller, for eample say *Person* and in this controller i have 3 Actions for example say *GetName*, *GetAge* and *GetDateOfBirth*. Now what i want is to place a check so that the user who are not loggedin can't get access to these action view.

For this i am trying to use `_start.cshtml` view. Which i placed inside the `Views/Person/` and i am expecting that whenever any user will access any view from inside *Person* folder than `_start.cshtml` view should run before any other view. And in *_start.cshtml* i placed a code to check for whether current user is logged in or not. But the _star.cshtml is not executing.

Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5):

> Now what i want is to place a check so that the user who are not
>   loggedin can't get access to these action view

That's absolutely not something that should be done in views but on the controller actions, by decorating them with the [`[Authorize]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) attribute. For example:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    ...
}
```

and you also have the possibility to specify one or more roles:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    ...
}
```

You could also decorate a controller with this attribute which would mean that all actions in it require authorization.